# JavaFX: ListView changes scrolling when selection changes

Tags: listview, javafx

I have a list view where I change the selected item programmatically (via method calls on the SelectionModel). This works fine, but the list view scrolls back to its top when the selection changes. This is rather annoying.

How can I keep the ListView at its scroll position when the selection changes?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand without an example, but did you try calling [ListView#scrollTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#scrollTo-T-) to the same value after programatically changing the selection?

Comment: Yes, it scrolls this entry to the top of the screen, rather than keeping the scrolling as it is. Is there some way to query the current scroll position?

Comment: I'm not sure... maybe the `FocusModel` is updated?

Comment: The problem was that I had a ScrollPane around the list view. This is not needed, as the list view adds scroll bars itself and caused the scroll-back-up thing on every update.